# Como importar um projeto android como módulo no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Eu estou tentando importar um projeto `Android` como módulo de outro projeto:

<kbd>[image: Como eu faço]</kbd>

Mas quando eu tento importar, o Gradle dá um erro dizendo que não consegue encontrar o método `android()` no arquivo `build.gradle` do módulo. Eu já tentei importar selecionando a pasta do projeto todo, e só a pasta "app", e ainda assim, o mesmo erro persiste.

<kbd>[image: esse é o erro]</kbd>

Aqui o que está escrito no `build.gradle` do módulo:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'br.ufc.great.arviewer.android/br.ufc.great.arviewer.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou salvar o outro projeto como módulo? Ou ele já está assim?

Comment: Não. Não sabia que precisava fazer isso. Poderia me dizer como se faz?

Comment: Messias, poderia incluir o `build.gradle` do módulo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei esse arquivo

Comment: Será que não faltou incluir a linha `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` no começo?

Comment: eu adicionei essa linha. Agora o erro mudou. Error:(29, 0) Could not find property 'natives' on configuration container.

Comment: Você conseguiria criar um novo módulo, importar as classes, salvar e ai importar no outro projeto? Outra coisa, não seria mais fácil você criar um novo módulo no projeto ao inves de importar?

Comment: Não, porque o módulo que eu quero importar é um projeto libGDX. Esse projeto não foi criado normalmente, foi criado pelo executável da lib. Tem uma série de configurações que eu não sei como funciona. Tentei apenas copiar as coisas pra dentro de um novo módulo, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Consegui resolver esse erro. Agora eu não consigo importar as classes do outro módulo :/ ta dificil

Comment: Tente fazer utilizando o passo a passo do seguinte tutorial: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162749/como-criar-uma-library-android-utilizando-o-android-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para importar as classes do outro modulo, tente adicionar isso ao arquivo `build.gradle` do seu projeto:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':seuModulo')
}
```