# Como criar uma Library-Android utilizando o Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, biblioteca, library

Tenho alguns projetos em processo de desenvolvimento e possuo diversas classes em comum para estes projetos. Gostaria de saber como criar e utilizar uma Lib das classes para que eu possa reutilizá-las sempre que eu precisar sem a necessidade de ficar reescrevendo estas classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtive sucesso na criação da minha Library. O tutorial mencionado na resposta do Leonardo Dias me forneceu um maior entendimento de como funciona a construção e compilação. No entanto não consegui atingir completamente meu objetivo apenas com ele.

Para fazer a exportação e criar um arquivo .JAR que pode ser implementado fiz da seguinte maneira:

**1º Passo:** Criar o projeto Android comum com as classes que serão reutilizadas.

**2º Passo:** Alterar o arquivo **app/build.gradle** na primeira linha para que fique da seguinte forma:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

**3º Passo:** Alterar a estrutura da "task" Android mantendo um corpo aproximadamente igual a este:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
```

**4º Passo:** Implementar ao final do arquivo a seguinte "task" que será a responsável pela criação do arquivo .JAR dentro do projeto:

```
    //Task para deletar os JAR velhos
    task deleteOldJar(type: Delete){
        delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
    }

    //Task para exportar conteudos para JAR
    task exportJar(type: Copy){
        from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
        into('release/')
        include('classes.jar')

        rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
    }
```

**5º Passo:** Dar um Sync no arquivo Gradle que acabou de ser editado para que ele construa a estrutura que será utilizada na geração do .JAR.

**6º Passo:** Acessar a janela de "Gradle projects" que se localiza no canto superior direito da tela e navegar até o arquivo `"Projeto">"Projeto">Tasks>other>exportJar` e executá-lo.

**7º Passo:** Acessar via Explorer a pasta do projeto e navegar até o local onde se encontra o arquivo que foi gerado. Provavelmente estará na pasta `C:\Users\"Usuario"\AndroidStudioProjects\"Projeto"\app\release` caso a instalação do Android Studio tenha sido feita como padrão.

*Neste momento o arquivo criado já pode ser utilizado em qualquer outro projeto Android utilizando os processos de importação comuns. Para isso basta apenas copiá-lo e colá-lo dentro da pasta "Libs" do projeto que utilizará as classes compartilhadas. Esta pasta não é visível caso esteja usando a estrutura de exibição de arquivos "Android". Para exibi-la dentro do Android Studio altere a exibição dos arquivos do projeto para o tipo "Project".*

**8º Passo:** Após copiar a biblioteca para a pasta Libs o arquivo será exibido dentro da IDE. Para adicionar ao projeto clique com o botão direito sobre ele e selecione a opção **Add as Library** e selecione em qual módulo a `lib` será incorporada.

**9º Passo:** Por fim para utilizar livremente as classes basta fazer um `import` na classe do projeto que está recebendo a lib. Assim já será possível acessar fluentemente todos os recursos criados na biblioteca.

***Considerações***
Para escrever este passo a passo eu assisti o seguinte vídeo como complemento:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i4I-Nph-Cw

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar um projeto normal

A diferença fica no arquivo **app/build.gradle**, que você precisa indicar ao build do gradle que este projeto é uma lib, então adicione as seguintes linhas no início do arquivo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Depois você vai precisar adicionar no arquivo **app/build.gradl**e as configurações sobre sua biblioteca e o local onde ela deve ser instalada, ou seja, o local onde fica o seu repositório.

O repositório pode ser uma URL da internet (se existir um servidor), ou até mesmo uma pasta local do computador, exemplo:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///home/ricardo/gradle/rep")

            pom.groupId = GROUP
            pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            pom.version = VERSION_NAME
        }
    }
}
task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)
```

Nesta caso foi criada a task  uploadArchives que define o repositório onde a lib deve ser instalada.

A última linha desta configuração indica que a task install depende da task uploadArchives. Portanto se você executar a task install será feito também o upload da lib para o repositório.

Segue um exemplo de como ficaria o arquivo **app/build.gradle** completo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            //repository(url: "file:///C:/gradle/rep/")
            repository(url: "file:///home/ricardo/gradle/rep")

            pom.groupId = GROUP
            pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            pom.version = VERSION_NAME
        }
    }
}
task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

[Veja nesse link](http://ricardolecheta.com.br/?p=371) a explicação completa de onde foi retirado esse tutorial

Ou você pode seguir a [Documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#CreateLibrary) que ensina como você compilar a sua lib em um arquivo **.jar**